# I'm trying to test for a named player head in slot 0b but I can't figure out whats wrong

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a head be an "engine" so that it can activate a flying system. It works, but it works with any type of head.

The command I am using is:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add equ {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:skull"}]}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: ok ill give you all the commands from right to left (its quite a small creation) command 1scoreboard players tag @a remove equ command 2:scoreboard players tag @a add equ {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:skull"}]} command 3:execute @a[tag=equ,rx=0,rxm=-90] ~ ~ ~ tp @p ~ ~0.2 ~

Comment: the problem is i cant find out how to name the skull so that it only works with the named skull but every time i try it it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test fpr a skull with a name (renamed by anvil or /give) try this:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add equ {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:skull",tag:{display:{Name:"Item Name"}}}]}
```

Replace *Item Name* with whatever name your item should have. For more information chech out the wiki:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags

EDIT:

If you want to test for heads with a custom skullowner try this:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add equ {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:skull",tag:{SkullOwner:"Player Name"}}]}
```

Replace *Player Name* with whatever player your item is of.

If you want to now how to achieve those itemes:

Hope it helped :)